Seeking Advice on Timing for Home Energy Audit and AC/Furnace Installation
I have an upcoming AC/furnace installation scheduled, as well as an appointment for a home energy audit. Currently, I’m relying on my HVAC technician to provide the best parts and service. However, conducting the home energy audit after the installation would give me a clearer picture of where my home stands in terms of energy efficiency.
That said, if I complete the audit before the AC/furnace installation, I would have a better understanding of what’s needed. For example, I could determine whether I need a 2.5-ton or 3-ton unit. This information would allow me to make a more informed decision about the installation or potentially reevaluate my options.
I’d appreciate your thoughts on this.

Unless you absolutely need to replace the HVAC, do the Energy audit first, The HVAC person has no way of knowing how the system will perform in your exact situation and will go by rules of thumb or just match the existing. Ideally, you want to make the changes recommended by the auditor first, see how the house performs over the year and then size the HVAC system.

Are you planning to run a Manual J load calculation on your house?
